# Javascript Chunk Array according to subArray length

Tags: javascript, arrays, chunks

I have a problem about chunking subarrays. As you see below, there are many `òbject` inside `detail`. I want to split them `if detail[i].length + detail[i+1].length >= 11` chunk array with 2, else chunk 3.

```
const isQuestions = 
  [ { question: ['ques 1?'], detail: [ {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 2'],  detail: [ {b:1}, {b:2}, {b:3}, {b:4}, {b:5}, {b:6}, {b:7}, {b:8} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 3?'], detail: [ {c:1}, {c:2}, {c:3}, {c:4}, {c:5}, {c:6}, {c:7} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 4'],  detail: [ {d:1}, {d:2}, {d:3}, {d:4} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 5'],  detail: [ {e:1}, {e:2}, {e:3}, {e:4} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 6'],  detail: [ {f:1}, {f:2}, {f:3}, {f:4} ] }
  , { question: ['ques 7'],  detail: [ {g:1}, {g:2}, {g:3}, {g:4} ] } 
  ]
```

Expected array be like;

```
[ [ { question: ['ques 1?'], detail: [ {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6} ] }
  , { question: ['ques 2'],  detail: [ {b:1}, {b:2}, {b:3}, {b:4}, {b:5}, {b:6}, {b:7}, {b:8} ] } 
  ]
, [ { question: ['ques 3?'], detail: [ {c:1}, {c:2}, {c:3}, {c:4}, {c:5}, {c:6}, {c:7} ] }
  , { question: ['ques 4'],  detail: [ {d:1}, {d:2}, {d:3}, {d:4} ] } 
  ]
, [ { question: ['ques 5'],  detail: [ {e:1}, {e:2}, {e:3}, {e:4} ] }
  , { question: ['ques 6'],  detail: [ {f:1}, {f:2}, {f:3}, {f:4} ] }
  , { question: ['ques 7'],  detail: [ {g:1}, {g:2}, {g:3}, {g:4} ] } 
] ]
```

As you see above, the sum of expected array's last part is 12. But It does not matter, the important thing is `arr[i] + arr[i+1] length`.

I did a function like inside map function. Because I have multiple array like this.

```
function isApsChunk(rawArray, size) {
    var returnedArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rawArray.length; i += size) {
        if (rawArray[i + 1])
            if (rawArray[i].detail.length + rawArray[i + 1].detail.length >= 11) {
                returnedArray.push(rawArray.slice(i, i + 2));
            } else {
                returnedArray.push(rawArray.slice(i, i + size));
            }
    }
    return [returnedArray];
}
console.log(isApsChunk(isQuestions, 3))
```

But the problem is that function takes array with the length 7, gives me 5.

Comment: @MisterJojo it has something like that you mentioned. But it is not important, just you think Object.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way:
with the help of [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

in this code the argument r (acronym of result [accumulator in doc MDN])
is initialized as follows:
`r = {resp: [], blk: null, len: 0, count: 0}`

`r.resp` becomes the final accumulator
`r.blk` points to the sub array to fill
`r.len = size` of the accumulation of arr detail
`r.count = r.blk.length`, linearity here has 3 by the `size` argument of the function

`{[i + 1]: next}` allows to point to the element `i + 1` and name it `next`, they guess undefined when it is outside the array (when we are on the last element, the next one does not exist and `!!next` become false

`!!next` is equivalent to [Boolean(next)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

```js
const isQuestions = 
  [ { question: ['ques 1?'], detail: [ {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 2'],  detail: [ {b:1}, {b:2}, {b:3}, {b:4}, {b:5}, {b:6}, {b:7}, {b:8} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 3?'], detail: [ {c:1}, {c:2}, {c:3}, {c:4}, {c:5}, {c:6}, {c:7} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 4'],  detail: [ {d:1}, {d:2}, {d:3}, {d:4} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 5'],  detail: [ {e:1}, {e:2}, {e:3}, {e:4} ] } 
  , { question: ['ques 6'],  detail: [ {f:1}, {f:2}, {f:3}, {f:4} ] }
  , { question: ['ques 7'],  detail: [ {g:1}, {g:2}, {g:3}, {g:4} ] } 
  ]  

const isApsChunk = (rawArray, size) => 
  rawArray.reduce((r,elm,i,{[i+1]:next}) =>
  {
  if (r.len===0 || r.len >= 11 || r.count >= size)
    {
    r.len   = 0
    r.count = 0
    r.blk   = []
    r.resp.push(r.blk )
    }
  r.len += elm.detail.length
  r.count++
  r.blk.push( elm )

  return (!!next)?r:r.resp
  },{ resp:[], blk:null, len:0, count:0 } )
  
console.log(  isApsChunk(isQuestions, 3) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: Can you add some comment blocks for more understanding, please?

Comment: @apsisx I added some explanations, need more ?